# something called spektrumanalysator has spammed my ubuntu gnome apps section

Tags: 21.04

These apps installed itself since i updated to ubuntu 21.04 from 20.04. i have no idea what they do nor do i want to break my system by removing them, any help would be appreciated.

[image: There are more such extensions installed]

[image: looks like this when opened]

---

```
karthik@knair:~$ grep -ri spektrumanalysator ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications /usr/local/share/applications
karthik@knair:~$
```

Comment: Please run `grep -ri spektrumanalysator ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications /usr/local/share/applications` and add command output to the question. Do you use your Ubuntu for audio production? Why do you not consider Ubuntu Studio for this purpose?

Comment: karthik@knair:~$ grep -ri spektrumanalysator ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications /usr/local/share/applications
    karthik@knair:~$

Comment: @N0rbert i dont use ubuntu for audio production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove relevant packages by

```
sudo apt-get autopurge 'lsp-plugins*'
```

Comment: thanks i did that and issue resolved but i don't know why did it get installed itself